# Moving files to read-only folder with node fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, fs

I have a problem with moving files from one directory to another with node.js fs tool. I can read them, but not write. I suspect the problem is in read-only property, which trows

> EPERM operation is not permitted 'C:\Andersen\Images\small'

Error mentions directory, in which I'm trying to write all this files.

```
    var filesystem = require("fs"); 

    files.forEach(function (file) {
       filesystem.renameSync(".\\Test", ".\\Images\\small");          
    });
```

I tried changing read-only property of the folder with Windows cmd

> attrib -r +s "C:\Andersen\Images"

but it didn't work. I have Windows 7 Pro, if it matters. Windows GNU doesn't work either. "Attribute changer" program did change property, but error still appears. Total Commander changing didn't work.
What can I do with this? Is there any way to write files into read-only folder with fs or suggest any other mode?

I will be thankful for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it turned out that problem was in fs.renameSync() function. That is why I used fs-extra and it's copy() function.

```
var filesystem = require("fs-extra");    

filesystem.copy(file,".\\Images\\big\\" + stat.size + ".jpg", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```